# Get single value of extended hash in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I have an extended hash (that I didn't write by myself) of which I need to extract a single value (i.e. I don't need to list all out).
Since this code get me the pairs of key/value

```
<#list tranlink as key,val>
   ${key} - ${val}
</#list>
```

That is

```
en_US - link_to_us
it_IT - link_to_it
```

How can I get the single value by key?
I've tried

```
${tranlink.en_US}
${tranlink[en_US]}
${tranlink["en_US"]}
```

But I always get an error.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: The errors I get are:
`The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> tranlink.en_US

The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> en_US 

The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> tranlink["en_US"]`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem here is that the keys in the backing Java `Map` aren't `String`-s, but `Locale` objects. So `#list` will work, but `tranlink.en_US` and `tranlink["en_US"]` will do the lookup with a `String` key, and so they find nothing. In FreeMarker 2.x, when using `.` or `[]` operators, the key is always a strings. If FreeMarker configuration allows it, you can call Java API like `tranlink?api.get(...)`, and that supports any type of key. But, you still will need the key `Locale` object from somewhere, as FreeMarker doesn't support creating `Locale` objects out-of-the-box.